# Use of scalastyleConfigUrl

Tags: scala, sbt, scalastyle

I am very new to Scala and SBT

I am trying to set up the project with Scalastyle. All works fine when running from command line, however I can't find a way to define the option as indicated on  the Scalastyle website 
http://www.scalastyle.org/sbt.html

I tried to add something like this in the `plugins.sbt`

> val scalastyleConfigUrl =
>   Some(url("http://www.scalastyle.org/scalastyle_config.xml"))

I am not sure how to validate if this is working; I would expect the `scalastyle_config.xml` to be downloaded at each compilation, obviously I am missing something.

Second part, I would like to automate scalastyle to run at each compilation/build. How can achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Scalastyle Stylesheet Download

The Stylesheet will only be downloaded once every 24 hours in the default configuration and stored in `scalastyleConfigUrlCacheFile`.

See documentation :

```
scalastyleConfigRefreshHours |  Integer |   If scalastyleConfigUrl is set, refresh it after this number of hours. Default value is 24.
```

## Example to use remote stylesheet in `compile`

Setting config url in `build.sbt`

```
(scalastyleConfigUrl in Compile) := Some(url("http://www.scalastyle.org/scalastyle_config.xml"))
```

## Run on every compile, by hand

Easy solution would be to run it by triggering it with `sbt` or `activator`

`sbt scalastyle compile`

## Redefine `compile` to run `scalastyle`

in `build.sbt`

```
compile <<= (compile in Compile).dependsOn((scalastyle in Compile).toTask(""))
```

You can also override the task definition or define a custom task: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html#modifying-an-existing-task

Comment: wow that works :) do you think any way to have the command integrated with Intellij's compile?

Comment: one more thing: if I run `sbt compile` I would expect it to download the `scalastyle_config.xml` file - it actually fails saying "config does not exist: scalastyle-config.xml"

Comment: if you give no remote url you have to run `sbt scalastyle-generate-config`.

Comment: there was a intellij plugin to run sbt tasks but i am not sure about the state it is in now

Comment: I am trying to set the remote url both from command line then into the sbt with `val scalastyleConfigUrl = Some(url("http://www.scalastyle.org/scalastyle_config.xml"))` none of them seems to work

Comment: try `(scalastyleConfigUrl in Compile) := Some(url("http://www.scalastyle.org/scalastyle_config.xml"))`will adapt answer